# Exclude auto generated folders in Android "Navigate File"

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there a way to disable auto-generated files or files from a certain folder when using "Navigate File" (Cmd + Shift + O on Mac) in Android Studio.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: no, so far no solution - annoying